# Code in app.js stopping CSS resource being loaded

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, web-applications

I have an interesting issue. I recently added some code to my app.js file to call my SQL server and return results.

The code works, and it returns the records I expect, however it stops my CSS file being returned, with an error 500. If I rem out the code which calls my SQL server, it works fine again.

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

// Create connection to database
var config =
{
    authentication: {
        options: {
            userName: '', // update me
            password: '' // update me
        },
        type: 'default'
    },
    server: '', // update me
    options:
    {
        database: '', //update me
        encrypt: true
    }
}
var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on('connect', function(err)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else
        {
            queryDatabase()
        }
    }
);

function queryDatabase()
{

    // Read all rows from table
    var request = new Request(
        "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Persons]",
        function(err, rowCount, rows)
        {
            console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
            process.exit();
        }
    );

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            console.log("%s\t%s", column.metadata.colName, column.value);
        });
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Here is my page being returned with no css, and the error displayed:

[image]

Anyone know what is going on here, and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Can you explain more about 'it stops my css file being returned'?

Comment: A error message screenshot will be helpful to locate your issue.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I've updated the OP with a screenshot.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192013/room-for-tony-ju-and-kat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it again. It works well. Here are the key points.

**prerequisite**

Just add those codes which you pasted in the question.

**1.install tedious**
[image]

**2.make sure the listen port is correct.**

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

**3.Set your sql server to allow access to Azure services**

[image]

The reason why I encountered the error 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.' is wrong port configuration.

Comment: Thanks Tony, all these things were set correctly but I'm still getting the issue. Another error I got in the developer console was 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. Plus the pages are very slow to load.

Comment: @Kat That is odd. I just encounter the warning message.

Comment: I'm not getting issues now I have changed my setup to use Visual Studio Code instead of trying to develop in the cloud. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.